# Ntpd client strange behavior

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

Jetson NX with latest Jetpack, NTP Ver. 4.2.8p10
I have some pools in /etc/ntp.conf (0.europe.pool.ntp.org)
When I try ntdate -q 0.europe.pool.ntp.org all is ok
[image: ntpdate scrn]
But there is nothing except one strange server in ntpq -p with no sync
[image: ntpq -p]
I have already tested 123 port with nmap with some pool servers and all is also ok
[image: nmap]

I cannot understand why ntp client is not working at all

Updated

Here is my /etc/ntp.conf file

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
# Leap seconds definition provided by tzdata
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list
# Enable this if you want statistics to be logged.
#statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/
statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

pool 0.europe.pool.ntp.org minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 iburst
pool 1.europe.pool.ntp.org minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 iburst
pool 2.europe.pool.ntp.org minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 iburst
pool 3.europe.pool.ntp.org minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 iburst

server 127.127.28.0 minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 iburst true
fudge 127.127.28.0 time1 0.200 flag1 1 refid GPSD
# By default, exchange time with everybody, but don't allow configuration.
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery
```

Comment: Do not post images when plain text will do.

Comment: The `ntpdate` command is querying remote servers, it is not looking at your local ntp config file. I assume `/etc/ntp.conf` has been configured with a server `10.113.100.250` which is not working. You need to edit and correct the conf file. You also need to look at the conf man page.

Comment: @Bib I have updated my post with /etc/ntp.conf file. There is no 10.113.100.250 server inside it

Comment: You conf file has 4 pools declared. You ntpq command only declares 1. I'd be looking to check whether that conf file is being used. I'd also be checking the logs for errors.